# How to safely forward/manage options between functions?

Tags: options, coding-style

Algorithms can often be splitted into smaller and reusable functions (that's a good thing).

However with this scheme it is not clear to me how to ensure the consistency of the option values and their proper forwarding across functions.

Imagine that you have 2 functions: `foo1` and `foo2`, where `a,b` are your algorithm parameters:

```
Options[foo1] = {a -> 1, b -> 2};

foo1[arg__, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
   Print["foo1 a=", OptionValue[a], " b=", OptionValue[b]]; 

Options[foo2] = {b -> -2};

foo2[arg__, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
   Print["foo2 b=", OptionValue[b]];
```

Now you want to define a `foo3` function that reuses `foo1` and `foo2`

```
Options[foo3] = {a -> 10, c -> 4};

foo3[opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Block[{},
   foo1[1, 2, FilterRules[{opts}, Options[foo1]]];
   foo2[4, 5, FilterRules[{opts}, Options[foo2]]];
   ];
```

Running this example:

```
foo3[]
```

prints:

> foo1 a=1 b=2
>
> foo2 b=-2

IMHO there are **two main issues**:

- the `a->10` default value is not forwarded
- incompatible option `b->2` for `foo1` and `b->-2` for `foo2` is not detected

---

**Another problem** is that `OptionsPattern[]` is very permissive:

```
foo[opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=opts

foo[2]
foo[{}]
foo[{{}}]
foo[a -> 1, b -> 2]
foo[{a -> 1, b -> 2}]
foo[{{a -> 1, b -> 2}}]
foo[{{{a -> 1, b -> 2}}}]
```

prints:

> foo[2]
>
> {}
>
> {{}}
>
> Sequence[a -> 1, b -> 2]
>
> {a -> 1, b -> 2}
>
> {{a -> 1, b -> 2}}
>
> {{{a -> 1, b -> 2}}}

This makes options processing tedious, for instance checking if an option with key `k` is present is not as simple as it should be. The code below

```
foo[k_Symbol,opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=MemberQ[Keys[opts],k]
```

does not work as expected:

```
foo[a,{}]              (* OK *)
foo[a,{a->1,b->2}]     (* OK *)
foo[a,{{a->1,b->2}}]   (* Problem *)
foo[a,a->1,b->2]       (* Problem *)
```

outputs:

> False
>
> True
>
> False <- Should be True
>
> False <- Should be True

**How to fix these problems?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated:**

To manage this I finally have introduced a small MMA package [SafeOptions](https://github.com/vincent-picaud/SafeOptions)

(I initially wanted to put all the details here but it was longer than expected, sorry for that).

To use the package

```
<<SafeOptions`
```

you must modify `foo3` as follows:

```
Options[foo3] = createOptionList[{a->10, b->1}, Options /@ {foo1, foo2}];

foo3[opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=      
    Block[{safeOpts},

          If[(safeOpts = getOptionList[Options[foo3], opts]) === $Failed, 
   Return[$Failed]];

          foo1[1, 2, filterOptionList[Options[foo1], safeOpts]]; 
          foo2[4, 5, filterOptionList[Options[foo2], safeOpts]];
    ];
```

Now

```
foo3[]
```

prints:

> foo1 a=10 b=1
>
> foo2 b=1

as expected. The options are **correctly forwarded**.

Also observe that if we do not provide the default option value `b->1`

```
Options[foo3] = createOptionList[{a->10}, Options /@ {foo1, foo2}]
```

**an error message is generated in case of incompatible option values**:

> safeOptions::incompatibleOptions: Some options are incompatibles {b->{2,-2}}
>
> $Failed

---

**Concerning OptionsPattern[]**: the package provides the `normalizeOptionPattern[]` function that transforms all these different forms into a well defined list of transformation rules. Now,

```
foo[opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=normalizeOptionPattern[opts]

foo[2]
foo[{}]
foo[{{}}]
foo[a -> 1, b -> 2]
foo[{a -> 1, b -> 2}]
foo[{{a -> 1, b -> 2}}]
foo[{{{a -> 1, b -> 2}}}]
```

prints:

> foo[2]
>
> {}
>
> {}
>
> {a -> 1, b -> 2}
>
> {a -> 1, b -> 2}
>
> {a -> 1, b -> 2}
>
> {a -> 1, b -> 2}

and

```
foo[k_Symbol,opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=MemberQ[Keys[normalizeOptionPattern[opts]],k]
```

works as expected:

```
foo[a,{}]              (* OK *)
foo[a,{a->1,b->2}]     (* OK *)
foo[a,{{a->1,b->2}}]   (* OK *)
foo[a,a->1,b->2]       (* OK *)
```

outputs:

> False
>
> True
>
> True
>
> True

---

For further details you can visit the [GitHub package page](https://github.com/vincent-picaud/SafeOptions) where there is a first version of the SafeOptions package. Feel free to test it/report bugs, etc.